# SQL - Checking to see if an element in a table has two other elements it is on the same row as

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Pardon my lack of correct terminology, I'm incredibly new to SQL.

I have a table named Food, it has 3 columns: id, name, and type.

ID | Name    | Type
1  | Chicken | Poultry
2  | Cabbage | Vegetable
3  | Chicken | Yum
4  | Popcorn | Yum

I wrote a function that returned 2 "types" (i.e. Poultry and Yum) and I'd like to check if any of my Foods have 2 types. Is there a way to write that function without specifically naming "Poultry" and "Yum"?

Comment: Can you show us the function you created? and Its my understanding that you want to show any rows that contain your 2 "types" (example: Poultry and Yum) but in general it can be any variable you pass into the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you group by the *name*, you can then check how many rows there are for each name:

```
SELECT Name,
       group_concat(Type)   -- if you want to konw the types
FROM Food
GROUP BY Name
HAVING count(*) >= 2;
```